# Android Studio installed on SSD but Android studio using 100% HDD

Tags: android-studio, hard-drive, solid-state-drive

I am facing a weird issue with the Android studio since last week.

I have installed Android Studio on SSD (C partition), My project is stored on SSD (J partition) SDK installed in SSD (C Partition) but Android studio eating up HDD and performance becomes too laggy.

I tried Cleaning and rebuild the project, Invalidate the cache and restart rebooting (Coldboot) the pc, HDD defrag but nothing worked.

Here are screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it myself, cold-boot the windows fixed this.

After a few days, this issue occurred again I reinstalled the windows. I guess this is an OS issue.

Edit-

The issue reproduced even after reinstalling the windows, after making some research I concluded this solution -

This issue is causing due to the Windows page file. Windows was using HDD to fulfill RAM requirements (yes, 8GB was not enough in my case).

**SOLUTION** -

**Permanent Solution** -
Upgrade RAM.

**Temporary Solution** -
Run only Android studio alone try to reduce RAM requirements.